# Alternative solutions to applying an overly large and detailed texture to a mesh

Tags: unity, textures, streaming

I have a very large spherical mesh in my Unity scene (the earth), to which one very large texture is applied (a map of the earth). Now it just so happens that Unity's max texture size (8192 pixels I believe) is not enough to capture the details I need on this huge mesh.

What's the proper way to deal with this situation in Unity? That is, not only overriding the 8192 pixels limitations (although that would be nice as a temporary solution), but also making sure the overhead won't become unbearable...

Is there a way to dynamically stream higher quality sections of textures as the camera gets closer to that specific part of the mesh?

Additionally, I see the Granite add-on (http://graphinesoftware.com/products/granite-for-unity) seems to do just this (if I understood it well), but it's only for Windows, and I'm developing on a Mac. Is there any other adding out there?

Comment: Remember that just because the Earth may be one "thing" does not mean it needs to be rendered as one mesh. If you're close enough to need more than 8192 pixels of, say, Australia, then you probably don't want to be spending any time or memory at all on polygons & pixels in Canada. So why put them all in the same mesh or texture?

Comment: I'm still figuring thing out, but is it easy to slice a mesh and its very large texture into chunks? Can I do this in Unity or should I use say Blender?

Comment: It depends on what your mesh is. If it's just a sphere, you'd probably do as well using a standard quad/plane as a patch - either one preexisting mesh that you transform in the shader to fit your sphere chunk, or constructed on the fly as needed. If it contains modelled continent detail, you might want to chop it up in a modelling tool. Similarly for your texture — do you have a source image of the whole surface, or do you build it from tiles the way mapping applications do?